# Is the word E "able" related to the suffix E "-able"?

Tags: etymology, english

***[able(1)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/able#Etymology_1)***

> From Middle English, from Old Northern French able, variant of Old French abile, habile, from *Latin* **habilis** ("easily managed, held, or handled; apt; skillful"), from **habeō** ("have, hold").

***[able(2)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/able#Etymology_2)***

> From Middle English ablen, from Middle English able (adjective).

***[-able](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able#Etymology)***

> From Middle English, from Old French, from *Latin* **-ābilis**, from -a- or -i- + bilis ("capable or worthy of being acted upon").
>
> **Not closely related etymologically**, though currently related semantically, to able.
>
> Replaced native Old English -bǣre ("bearing, making, worth"), from Proto-Germanic *bēriz, *bērijaz; and -lic ("like, having the quality of"), from Proto-Germanic *-līkaz.
> Compare German -bar, Dutch -baar.

What's the etymology relationship between these words? Why the description is "not closely related"?

Comment: Are these etymologies drawn from the OED? I am looking for the sources used in this exchange. Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The Latin roots of the English word ***able*** are:

> - The verb **habeo**: "to have, hold"
> - The suffix **-bilis**: "that ought or can easily be `[verb]`ed"

The (unattested) Latin form was **habibilis*, as mentioned by Sihler and noted by Tom Recht below. In classical Latin, this had been shortened to *habilis*, as it often happens with double syllables (called *haplology*). The *h-* had disappeared in certain French forms and dialects by the time the word was borrowed by English, and *-lis* regularly evolved into *-le* in French, resulting in English acquiring the word *able*.

---

The Latin root of the English suffix ***-able*** is:

> - The suffix **-bilis**: "capable or worthy of being `[verb]`ed"

The *-a-* was originally only present in verbs whose stems ended on *-a-*, such as *ama-re* "to love", resulting in *ama-bilis* "worthy of being loved"; however, this was later extended to other formations with *-bilis*, resulting in an an alternative suffix *-abilis*.

It is possible that the *-ilis* part in *-bilis* is related to the separate suffix *-ilis* as used in *habilis*, but I cannot find a definitive etymology for *-bilis*.

Comment: Sihler (New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin) derives _habilis_ by haplology from the expected *_habi-bilis_. He derives _-bilis_ from a Proto-Italic _-θlis_ (with anaptyctic _-i-_), presumably from the same PIE _-dhl-_ that shows up in the instrumental suffix _-dhlo-_. So the answer would be that they are partially related, i.e. _able_ historically contains _-able_.

Comment: @TomRecht: Ah, good work! Meillet didn't mention *habibilis*, but I will trust Sihler in this. Do you happen to know how confident he is about the derivation of *-bilis* from  *-θlis > -dhlo-?* I remember seeing *-dhlo-* mentioned by some etymologists, but they seemed uncertain. // By the way, does Sihler give the etymology of most Latin affixes? Does he also mention *-(i)lis*?

Comment: Sihler's discussion is under the rubric of "Anaptyxis in Latin" (p. 90), so he doesn't explicitly etymologize these affixes; but among his examples of anaptyxis is _stabilis_, which he states is from PItal. * _staθlis_. The connection with PIE _-dhlo-_ is my own interpretation (hence "presumably"), but I would guess Sihler thinks the same since in the same line he also mentions _stabulum_ < * _staθlom_, which certainly contains that suffix. I don't think he gives an etymology for _-(i)lis_, or for most other derivational suffixes, except incidentally by way of exemplification.

Comment: @TomRecht: OK thanks! From what I remember reading elsewhere, the connection between -dhlo- and -bul-[us|a|um] seemed to be accepted, but they were vague about the connection between *-bilis* and *-bul-*, and also vague about the connection between *-dhlo-* and *-bilis*...